# Select field in a table cell is sending results

Tags: html, forms, select

I have a HTML table with a form in each row. The value of the select box does not get passed in my form scope if it is within it own table cell. If however the whole form is in a single table cell the value does get passed. Is there any reason for this? Below is an eample of the working and not working code

WORKING

```
<tr>
                                <td>
                                <form name="1" method="post" class="mainForm" action="/campaigns/interface/1318">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="interfaceFiledUpdate[id]"> 
                                    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="updateInterfaceField">
                                    <input type="text" name="interfaceFiledUpdate[name]" value="telFax" class="tableForm">
                                    <div class="selector" id="uniform-undefined"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;">FIRSTNAME</span><select name="interfaceFiledUpdate[columnName]" style="opacity: 0;">
                                                <option value="">Select Column</option>

                                                <option value="ID">ID</option>

                                                <option value="DIALID">DIALID</option>

                                        </select></div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="greyishBtn">

                                </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

NOT WORKING

```
<tr>
<form name="1" method="post" class="mainForm" action="/campaigns/interface/1318">   <input type="hidden" value="1" name="interfaceFiledUpdate[id]"> 
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="updateInterfaceField">
<td>
<input type="text" name="interfaceFiledUpdate[name]" value="telFax" class="tableForm">
</td>
<td>
<div class="selector" id="uniform-undefined">
    <span style="-moz-user-select: none;">FIRSTNAME</span>
    <select name="interfaceFiledUpdate[columnName]" style="opacity: 0;">
        <option value="">Select Column</option>

        <option value="ID">ID</option>

        <option value="DIALID">DIALID</option>
    </select></div>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="greyishBtn">
</td>
</form>
</tr>
```

Comment: you should not use a form as a table's direct child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML elements (e.g. table, form, ul) have a schema. For HTML to be valid - and sometimes to even work - the schema must be adhered to. In this case, your HTML is invalid because 'form' elements cannot be children of 'table' elements. While invalid examples of HTML may still work as expected, this is not guaranteed. This is a case of the latter. You can check your HTML's validity [here](http://validator.w3.org/).